# First time loading with URLLoader is very slow, subsequent loads are OK

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, urlloader

I am having a hard time figuring out why this is happening. I am trying to load some variables from a server with URLLoader and URLVariables. It works without errors, but the first batch of data takes forever to load (like 25+ seconds), and all subsequent loads are OK (~1-2 seconds).

```
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.command = "commandType";
[... other variables...]            

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("address");
request.data = requestVars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLaunchResponse, false, 0, true);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
urlLoader.load(request);
```

I am simply stumped. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try to have look at network (for example Developer Tools in Chrome) to isolate the source of the problem (server-side vs. client-side).

Comment: How much data is being downloaded? When is it being downloaded (i.e. how long after startup)? We need more info here.

Comment: Solved it in the end, thanks to Petr (I don't know why I didn't think of sniffing the HTTP traffic in the first place, I've done that before, I guess I'm braindead today). The problem was on the server side, which was sending me a 30+ MB JSON object (text only) instead of a 5-10 KB one, and it simply took a long time for the client to download the entire data.

Anyway, thanks for your thoughts!